# TStringStream issue in Japanese localization

Tags: delphi, unicode, ansi

I have the following setup:
- Windows system language is English.
- I use Delphi 10.1 Berlin.
- In Windows Region & Language/Country set to Japan.
- Region/Administrative/Language for non-Unicode programs set to Japanese (Japan).

I have implemented communication client/server using strings.
Let's skip the question 'why not bytes' for now. I want to show the issue and find the reason why.

I write 2 things into TStringStream:

1. Header: which includes its size of Int64 (8 bytes), object size of Int64 (8 bytes) and class name: Header length - 2*SizeOf(Int64).
2. object (TComponent descendant)

---

```
procedure ComponentToStream(AComponent: TComponent; AStream: TStream; out HL,OL: Int64);
var
  CN: TBytes;
  MS1: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MS1 := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    CN := TEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(AComponent.ClassName);
    SaveComponentToStream(MS1, AComponent);
    OL := MS1.Size;
    MS1.Position := 0;
    HL := SizeOf(HL) + SizeOf(OL) + Length(CN);
    AStream.Write(HL,SizeOf(HL));
    AStream.Write(OL,SizeOf(OL));
    AStream.Write(CN[0], Length(CN));
    MS1.SaveToStream(AStream);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(MS1);
  end;
end;
```

---

```
function PrepareDataBeforeSend(Component: TComponent): string;
var
  HL, OL: Int64;
  SS: TStringStream;
begin
  SS := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.Unicode);
  try
    ComponentToStream(Component, SS, HL, OL);
    Result := SS.DataString;
    SS.SaveToFile('Orginal stream data.debug');
  finally
    FreeAndNil(SS);
  end;
```

The result of this method saved in file here
[click](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mpvQQWpC7pnuSqQP_bOzul2A131PeIwS/view?usp=sharing).

To verify the data I used code below right after calling of one above.

```
SS := TStringStream.Create({PrepareDataBeforeSend result}, TEncoding.Unicode);
SS.SaveToFile('New stream data.debug');
SS.Free;
```

Saved binary can be found here [Click](https://drive.google.com/file/d/194yYasyfr_SzasSVxtFP4dz9lxW_VoCK/view?usp=sharing)

And now 2 problems:

1. If I don't specify explicitly TEncoding.Unicode encoding in constructor of TStringStream, then TEncoding.Default will be used. But for Japanese code page it is ANSII and for English it is Unicode. As a result object size I read later

   ```
   SS.Read(OL, SizeOf(OL));
   ```

   is wrong.
   Here's the binary to compare. See 8-15 bytes [Click](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XrChEE5jBk3kxlUMabg5mG8qmQBnQc3v/view?usp=sharing)
2. OK, issue 1 was resolved, but still the binary I saved for verification does not match the original one: there is 1 byte missing at the end.

Can anyone tell where is a problem?

Important: there is no issues if I have English localization!!

Comment: This is all far to complex. Save the data as binary, and then transform to a base64 encoded string for transmission as text. Or, transmit as binary rather than text.

Comment: Note that TStringStream is meant to contain text only and not binary data. Even if SaveComponentToStream uses a textual representation (which we cannot see here), at least writing the Int64 values as binary will probably do some harm.

Comment: `TStringStream` is NOT suitable for binary data, and certainly not when using the `DataString` property, which is going to unconditionally convert the stream's content to UTF-16. Use `TMemoryStream` instead. And why use `TEncoding.Unicode` (UTF-16) instead of `TEncoding.UTF8` for your string data? UTF-8 is generally better for network transmissions and storage.

Comment: English localization probably uses pure ASCII. That is very likely why it is no problem. FWIW, it is ANSI, not ANSII. Or did you mean ASCII? And you don't think I'll download something without a preview, do you?